# jQuery table.wrap() causes layout issues

Tags: jquery, css-tables

I'll post a more detailed code snippet later (don't have VPN access right now) but is there anything usual that can cause strange layout issues in the case below:

```
<body>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <table id="container">...</table>
</body>
```

The top level `<div>`s are `float: left; width: 100%`

When I try to wrap the table using:

```
$('table#container').wrap('<div id="body_content"></div>');
```

The content of the first `<div>` gets messed up (seems to duplicate the menu bar I have there).

**UPDATE**
Just found `<script>` tags like the following nested inside the table, when I remove those before wrapping the table the issue goes away. Any insight into this would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think we need to see a little more HTML, and the CSS associated with the _body_content_ ID. And can you elaborate on _messed up_ a little more please?

Comment: Yeah, I'll post the entire example tonight I was just hoping someone had a similar experience they can share. As I mentioned the menu bar in the first div (menu is composed of several sub divs) seems to get duplicated so I see the menu twice and it wraps around and covers up part of the next div.

Comment: And the DOM for that div does not change at all, the 'extra' menu magically appears when I wrap the table.

Comment: strange, I look forward to your code tonight and will see if I can't help at that time.

Comment: While trying to clean up the HTML and make it post-worthy I think I found the cause of the issue (although I'm not sure why it has this effect). The `table` that I'm wrapping has `script` tags nested in it (ie loading jquery), so when I removed those before calling `wrap` the problem went away. If you have any thoughts on why this happens I'll be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was nested `<script>` tags, in particular a nested tag which loaded jQuery. Removing the script tags before calling `wrap()` seems to fix the issue.