# Is it always safe to remove a script include tag after document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a pretty strange 'assembly' of an HTML file going on, with `<script>` tags sprinkled throughout in various areas (can't do anything about that). One of these (deeply nested) is an include for jQuery. I need to remove the DOM element that has this jQuery script tag, so I want to make sure that is a safe operation. I'm assuming that since jQuery has already been loaded into memory I should be fine (and everything seems to work ok) but just wanted to verify.

Not relevant to this question but if you need to know why I would want to do such a thing take a look at [jQuery table.wrap() causes layout issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903237/jquery-table-wrap-causes-layout-issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't cause problems, except when the script tags are expected to exist in the DOM (for whatever reason).

Comment: +1. One reason to keep particular SCRIPT tags is if the SCRIPT tag used for jQuery templates - http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html (but in this case it will not contain JavaScript, but rather HTML).